# Rails Relationship Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, relationship

I have a HABTM relation ship between users and channels, where the user is subscribed to the channel. I want to show an "unsubscribe link" if the user is already subscribe to the channel. How do I test if the  user is part of channel.users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling:

```
channel.users.include? user
```

for the user you want to test. See the [Ruby documentation on Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002203) for more info. Good luck!

Comment: I used  <% link_to "Unsubscribe", '#' if @channel.users.include? current_user %>  but the link doesn't show up although the current_user is there

Comment: you'll have to wrap the link_to erb snippet in a block, like this:`<% if @channel.users.include? current_user %><% link_to "Unsubscribe", unsubscribe_path %><% end %>` with newlines, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a few different ways to do this, but here's a simple one:

```
@user.channels.include? @channel 

=> true/false
```